# Modifying a Packet's Outer IP TOS on an Docker Overlay Network

Tags: iptables, docker, tshark

I have a packet sent from a container on a self-defined overlay network using `docker create network --driver=overlay` with a TOS of 0x08. However, the docker overlay network wraps this L2 packet with a VXLAN header and then an outer udp, ip, and ethernet. Thus, the outer IP packets TOS no longer matches the TOS of the inner, so when it heads towards the physical NIC, the packet can't processed by the original traffic control rules anymore (controlling flow into different queues). For example. a packet captured using tshark looks like this. [image]

As shown, the outer IP TOS is now set to T0.

**How would I alter the outer IP TOS before it reaches the TC qdiscs?** I have tried looking at iptables and figured out that they might pass through filter's table `OUTPUT` chain and/or mangle's table `POSTROUTING` chain as shown below

```
# mangle
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
POSTROUTING_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere


# filter
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I think this because I sent large amounts of packets and saw the packets counter go up at those tables. However, I am not advanced enough with iptables to accomplish what I want. Is there any other way?